# Search in a container of objects with PHP

Tags: php

I have a container with some methods like `add`, `get`, and `search`, and within that class I have a variable that is an array holding instances of `Car`. How to make that object searchable by its name?

For example:

```
class Container {
  private $cars = [];

  public function __construct(array $cars = [])
  {
    $this->cars = $cars;
  }

  public function add($key, Car $car)
  {
    $this->cars[$key] = $car;
  }

  public function get($key)
  {
    return $this->cars[$key];
  }

  public function search($car)
  {
    // ...
  }
};

class Car {
  private $name;

  public function __construct($name = null)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function setName($name)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }

}
```

Comment: Use a `foreach()` loop that gets the name of the car and compares it to `$car`. What could be simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need some sort of iterative search like a `foreach()` or `array_filter()`.

For example:

```
public function search($car)
{
    $matches = array();
    foreach ($this->cars as $car) {
        if ($car->getName() === $car) {
            $matches[] = $car;
        }
    }

    return $matches;
}
```

Or

```
public function search($car)
{
    return array_filter($this->cars, function ($v) use ($car) {
        return $v->getName() === $car;
    });
}
```